# objective c Delegate on a existing category methods

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I want my class to delegate on the same methods of    NSObject (NSURLConnectionDelegate) category. But I always get " unrecognized selector" when trying to delegate. Here a simple code I use to test. Where did I go wrong?

```
@interface DelegateTest : NSObject
{
id intenalDelegate;
}

-(void) setDelegate: (id) delegate;
-(void) executeDelegateMethod;

@end


@implementation DelegateTest

-(void) setDelegate:(id) delegate{

intenalDelegate = [delegate retain];
}
-(void) executeDelegateMethod{
if([intenalDelegate      respondsToSelector:@selector(connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:)]) {
    return  [intenalDelegate connection:nil canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:nil];}

}
@end
```

In the classe I re-implemented the method I am requesting, I wrote:

```
DelegateTest * test = [[DelegateTest alloc]init];
[test setDelegate:self];
[test executeDelegateMethod];
```

but I got "unrecognized selector" error. Thanks indvance for any adevice.

Answer (score 0):

InternalDelegate is of type id so the compiler has NO IDEA what methods are on that object. You normally declare delegates as follows...

```
@protocol MyDelegate<NSObject> {
    - (void)myMethod;
}
```

Then in the interface you declare the instance variable as...

```
id<MyDelegate> internalDelegate;
```

Remember though with properties to use the assign attribute as you don't own the delegate...

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyDelegate> internalDelegate;
```

Note: that making the delegate implement the NSObject protocol ensures you can call respondsToSelector on it.

Comment: I thought the protocol was not necessary because NSObject (NSURLConnectionDelegate) category already decleare and implements the method I'd like to call to NSObject class. I did the changed you proposed but still does not work.@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject> 
 - (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace;
@end
@interface DelegateTest : NSObject
{
  id<MyDelegate> internalDelegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyDelegate> internalDelegate;


-(void) executeDelegateMethod;

@end

Comment: I found out. I am very sorry... The code was inside a static method so self was not correct. I really apologize.

Comment: "InternalDelegate is of type id so the compiler has NO IDEA what methods are on that object." *Unrecognized selector* is a runtime error, not a compiler error. Although it looks like Marco C already solved his problem.